# kotlin couroutine async not working in viewModelScope in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to do 2 network requests ,one after another, but only first one is going, second one is never getting executed : Here is my code

```
fun getData(todaysDateStart: Long, todaysDateEnd: Long) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val job1 = async {
                dataManager.getAllListsWithTaskCount()
                    .collect { taskListsFromDb: List<TaskListAndCount> ->
                        if (taskListsFromDb.isNotEmpty()) {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                taskListAndCount.value = Resource.Success(taskListsFromDb)
                            }
                        } else {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                taskListAndCount.value = Resource.Loading
                            }
                            val response = safeApiCall {
                                dataManager.getUserTaskLists(
                                    dataManager.getUserId(),
                                    dataManager.getAccessToken()
                                )
                            }

                            when (response) {
                                is Resource.Success -> {
                                    val jsonObject = response.data.asJsonObject
                                    if (jsonObject["success"].asBoolean) {
                                        insertTaskListsInDb(jsonObject)
                                    } else {
                                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                            taskListAndCount.value =
                                                Resource.Error(IOException(jsonObject.get("message").asString))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                is Resource.Error -> {
                                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                        taskListAndCount.value = response
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            job1.await()

            val job2 = async {
                dataManager.getTasksForToday(todaysDateStart, todaysDateEnd)
                    .collect { tasksAndListFromDb: List<TaskAndTaskList> ->
                        if (tasksAndListFromDb.isNotEmpty()) {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                taskAndTaskList.value = Resource.Success(tasksAndListFromDb)
                            }
                        } else {

                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                taskAndTaskList.value = Resource.Loading
                            }
                            val response = safeApiCall {
                                dataManager.getUserTasks(
                                    dataManager.getUserId(),
                                    dataManager.getAccessToken()
                                )
                            }

                            when (response) {
                                is Resource.Success -> {
                                    val jsonObject = response.data.asJsonObject
                                    if (jsonObject["success"].asBoolean) {
                                        insertTasksInDb(jsonObject)
                                    } else {
                                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                            taskAndTaskList.value =
                                                Resource.Error(IOException(jsonObject["message"].asString))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                is Resource.Error -> {
                                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                        taskListAndCount.value = response
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            job2.await()
        }

    }

    private suspend fun insertTaskListsInDb(jsonObject: JsonObject) {
        val taskListsJsonArray = jsonObject["task_lists"].asJsonArray
        val taskListsFromNetwork: MutableList<TaskList> = arrayListOf()
        taskListsJsonArray.forEach { taskListJsonElement: JsonElement ->
            taskListsFromNetwork.add(
                TaskList(
                    0,
                    taskListJsonElement.asJsonObject["list_slack"].asString,
                    taskListJsonElement.asJsonObject["name"].asString,
                    taskListJsonElement.asJsonObject["color"].asString
                )
            )
        }
        dataManager.insertTaskLists(taskListsFromNetwork)
    }

    private suspend fun insertTasksInDb(jsonObject: JsonObject) {
        val tasksJsonArray = jsonObject["tasks"].asJsonArray
        val tasksAndListFromServer = mutableListOf<Task>()
        tasksJsonArray.forEach { taskJsonElement: JsonElement ->
            tasksAndListFromServer.add(
                Task(
                    0,
                    taskJsonElement.asJsonObject["user_task_id"].asString,
                    taskJsonElement.asJsonObject["task_slack"].asString,
                    taskJsonElement.asJsonObject["task"].asString,
                    taskJsonElement.asJsonObject["date_time"].asLong,
                    taskJsonElement.asJsonObject["list_slack"].asString
                )
            )
        }

        dataManager.insertTasks(tasksAndListFromServer)
    }
```

`job2.await` never executes. Please help.

**UPDATE 1 :**
I ended up doing this but it's still not executing the second network request :

```
un getData(todaysDateStart: Long, todaysDateEnd: Long) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dataManager.getAllListsWithTaskCount()
            .collect { taskListsFromDb: List<TaskListAndCount> ->
                if (taskListsFromDb.isNotEmpty())
                    taskListAndCount.value = Resource.Success(taskListsFromDb)
                else {

                    taskListAndCount.value = Resource.Loading

                    val response = safeApiCall {
                        dataManager.getUserTaskLists(
                            dataManager.getUserId(),
                            dataManager.getAccessToken()
                        )
                    }

                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            val jsonObject = response.data.asJsonObject
                            if (jsonObject["success"].asBoolean) {
                                insertTaskListsInDb(jsonObject)
                            } else {
                                taskListAndCount.value =
                                    Resource.Error(IOException(jsonObject.get("message").asString))
                            }
                        }
                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            taskListAndCount.value = response
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        dataManager.getTasksForToday(todaysDateStart, todaysDateEnd)
            .collect { tasksAndListFromDb: List<TaskAndTaskList> ->
                if (tasksAndListFromDb.isNotEmpty())
                    taskAndTaskList.value = Resource.Success(tasksAndListFromDb)
                else {
                    taskAndTaskList.value = Resource.Loading

                    val response = safeApiCall {
                        dataManager.getUserTasks(
                            dataManager.getUserId(),
                            dataManager.getAccessToken()
                        )
                    }

                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            val jsonObject = response.data.asJsonObject
                            if (jsonObject["success"].asBoolean) {
                                insertTasksInDb(jsonObject)
                            } else {
                                taskAndTaskList.value =
                                    Resource.Error(IOException(jsonObject["message"].asString))
                            }
                        }
                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            taskListAndCount.value = response
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are executing job1 just after creating you call await(), so maybe job1 never ends, so job2 could never be created? maybe create 2 different viewModelScope.launch instead of single one?

Comment: You're consuming Flows. There's no point in using `async`, use `launch` instead.

Comment: No, use neither `async` nor `launch`. It's just two suspendable calls in a sequence.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Vicky, you can create `viewModelScope.launch{val first =  async(Dispatchers.IO){firstNumber()}  val second = async(Dispatchers.IO) { secondNumber() } }`, which will give you `first.await()` and `second.await()` too, make sure `first` and `second` method should be `suspend` function

Comment: @Vicky when you call `collect`, the thread starts consuming the Flow and that's why it seems to be blocked. You need to start another coroutine with `launch` to attend that consumption.

Comment: @GlennSandoval Oh...... Thanks

Comment: @GlennSandoval OP wants to make one request after the other. You seem to suggest that they make two concurrent requests?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I understood just exactly that, 2 concurrent requests despite the "one after another" since it seems like Vicky is expecting to start the second request (immediately) after the first one. If he needs to finish the first request before starting the second one then you're right, concurrent requests have nothing to do here.

Comment: If it's two concurrent requests, then each of the two Flow expressions should be in its own `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` block, with no nested `async` or `launch`.